# How do I use Cordova plugins?

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-plugins

The instructions on [Cordova's Battery Status plugin page](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-battery-status/index.html) say that I just need to run `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-battery-status`.

When I do that, cordova does add

- `<plugin name="cordova-plugin-battery-status" spec="^2.0.2" />` to my config.xml file
- a directory called cordova-plugin-battery-status inside my plugins folder,
- a node_modules folder of the same name
- and `"cordova-plugin-battery-status": "^2.0.2",` as a dependency inside my package.json

The instructions suggest this example:

```
window.addEventListener("batterystatus", onBatteryStatus, false);

function onBatteryStatus(status) {
    console.log("Level: " + status.level + " isPlugged: " + status.isPlugged);
}
```

...which I put in my Vue project's main.js file to try it out.

The instructions say this plugin is compatible with the browser platform. So I ran `cordova platform add browser` and `cordova run browser`, which started a localhost instance of the app. However, plugging the computer in and out did nothing.

When instead I triggered the plugin by a button click, I got a type error: "Cannot read property 'level' of undefined"

I've tried other plugins, and my core non-plugin Cordova features are working fine, but I just can't get cordova plugins to work.

I'm *not* using Ionic. I'm using Vue, OnsenUI, firebase, and the Cordova CLI.

I would think I need to initialize this plugin within my main.js file and/or write an import/from statement but the installation instructions say nothing of that.

Comment: Wild guess: while compatible in the sense it wont crash it doesn't guarantee all browsers on all devices and platforms will have the necessary API's to give you that information. It sounds to me like the sort of thing you'll only get on a small subset of targets.

Answer (score 0):

This page https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-battery-status says

> This plugin provides an implementation of an old version of the
>   Battery Status Events API.

Looking on the web for the Battery Status Events API the first result is this page 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Battery_Status_API, that says

> Obsolete This feature is obsolete. Although it may still work in some
>   browsers, its use is discouraged since it could be removed at any
>   time. Try to avoid using it.

I've also found that there is a phonegap-plugin-battery-status plugin https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-battery-status that may use a newer version of the battery api https://www.w3.org/TR/battery-status/.

Maybe you can try to remove cordova-plugin-battery-status and try phonegap-plugin-battery-status.

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to use phonegap plugins in a project created by the Cordova CLI? I do have the phonegap cli installed globally, and I ran `phonegap plugin add phonegap-plugin-battery-status` ... but after i ran `npm run build` and `cordova build ios --buildFlag='-UseModernBuildSystem=0'`, the xcode archive failed, which was working before that phonegap plugin installation...